# HTML.Display() not displaying anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just starting out with mvc and have the following code:

```
@model AzureDemo.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Interests";
}

<h2>Interests</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Interests
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var interest in Model.Interests) {
     <tr>
         <td>
            @Html.Display(interest)
        </td>
        //Tried like this
        <td>
            @Html.Display("id", interest.ToString())
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The Interests property in User is simply a list of strings. I'm trying to display each interest in a table for a user. I also tried putting a string like "test" in Html.Display, or tried using ToString() but still nothing.

Comment: why dont you direct use? like this : `<td>@interest</td>`

Comment: that worked! If you put it as an answer I will accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use directly model item like this

```
@foreach (var interest in Model.Interests) {
 <tr>
     <td>
        @interest
    </td>
    // or this 
    <td>
        @interest.ToString()
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

or if you show html codes in your view then this is more safety

```
@foreach (var interest in Model.Interests) {
 <tr>
     <td>
        @Html.Raw(interest)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Also thanks for this chance ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you using a display template and get rid of all foreach loops in your view:

```
@model AzureDemo.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Interests";
}

<h2>Interests</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout")
</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Interests
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Interests)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then define the corresponding display template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the Interests collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Interest.cshtml`):

```
@model AzureDemo.Models.Interest
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Text)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out, however I already told AliRiza I would accept his answer :)